# Check for daylight saving time with WMI on Vista/Win7

Tags: windows, wmi, dst

How do I find out if the computer I'm on has daylight saving time in effect? (preferably using WMI)

According to [this article at TechNet](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/en-us/86090fa4-e409-4462-ac6c-4bc47f128d23), I could query `SELECT DaylightInEffect FROM Win32_ComputerSystem`, but the property `DaylightInEffect` is not supported on Vista or Win7. As my program will run on various systems (XP, Vista, 7), I would appreciate some portable way of finding out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documented supported OS list is not accurate, this works fine on Win7 when I try it.  I can't think of any reason it wouldn't be supported on any other OS, it is easy to find out with the Win32 API (GetTimeZoneInformation).

You can use [WmiCodeCreator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) for a quick check.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to work in practice. Yay for undocumented API.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a boolean function that is implemented using the WMI query referenced in the question.

*(Related: [How Can I Determine My Time Zone Offset Using VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13980541/1497596))*

```vbs
Function IsDaylightInEffect()
    Const sComputer = "."

    Dim oWmiService : Set oWmiService = _
        GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
                  & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set cItems = oWmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each oItem In cItems
        IsDaylightInEffect = oItem.DaylightInEffect
        Exit For
    Next
End Function
```