# Determine my time zone offset using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, timezone, wmi, utc, timezone-offset

How can I determine my **time zone offset** using **VBScript**?

The Windows OS provides the `TZ` environment variable. For Eastern Standard Time (New York), its value is `EST5EDT`. However, I am looking for the signed integer offset from UTC. (This is **-5** for Eastern Standard Time.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a revised function that appears to account for Daylight Saving Time. *(Inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1797758/1497596).)*

```vb
Function GetTimeZoneOffset()
    Const sComputer = "."

    Dim oWmiService : Set oWmiService = _
        GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
                  & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set cItems = oWmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each oItem In cItems
        GetTimeZoneOffset = oItem.CurrentTimeZone / 60
        Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

---

***[Original function that does NOT account for Daylight Saving Time.]***

Here is my answer to my question ([original source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/daf4b666-fcb6-46ad-becc-689e6daf49ed/)).

For Eastern Standard Time (New York), this VBScript function will return **-5**:

```vb
Function GetTimeZoneOffset()
    Const sComputer = "."

    Dim oWmiService : Set oWmiService = _
        GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
                  & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Dim cTimeZone : Set cTimeZone = _
        oWmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_TimeZone")

    Dim oTimeZone
    For Each oTimeZone in cTimeZone
        GetTimeZoneOffset = oTimeZone.Bias / 60
        Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for DST?

Comment: @Alex - Please let me know if my revised function now accounts for Daylight Saving Time on your system.

Comment: For anyone searching, this method will actually allow you to accurately query for time-based Event Viewer events via WMI. You can then do calculation to account for the default-writing of events as UTC.