# Convert Time to UTC vbScript

Tags: datetime, vbscript, asp-classic, timezone, utc

I have the following function which does fine at converting current time to UTC time.

```
Function toUtc(byVal dDate)
    Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    toUtc = dateadd("n", oShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias"), cDate(dDate))
End Function
```

However, I am thinking that this does not adequately handle conversion of future or historical dates to UTC, since the function would need to know the offset of the server's timezone at the time of the date that is being converted, and whether or not it was during daylight savings time or not.

How can I get around this?

I am using vbScript/Classic ASP on windows server with IIS7.5

To clarify, this has nothing to do with formatting the date. It is all about converting to UTC from the server timezone for historical dates. During Daylight savings time, the offset will be off by 60 minutes if I try to convert a datetime which occurred in standard time.

For example:

Lets say that today, 2013-02-19 (non daylight-savings time), I want to covert a timestamp from say, 2008-06-05 (during daylight savings period) from PDT (my server timezone) to UTC. using the method in my function will give me a value which is 60 minutes off from the correct value (because the CURRENT time is PST (not PDT), the offset will be incorrect for that historical date).

In other words, the timezone offset of the input date could be UTC-7 or UTC-8 depending on whether or not DST was observed on that particular date. I need to calculate the correct UTC date for the input date and I need the code to work whether or not DST is observed on current date.

Comment: Since you can use javascript on the serverside too, I'd suggest you use javascripts toUTCString()

Comment: Thanks @AardVark71, I handn't thought of that option. I am going to do some unit tests on that and see how it comes out, and will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Works like a charm. I will post my final solution in a few.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up implementing at the suggestion of @AardVark71.

I put this in my func.asp file:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    function toUtcString(d) {
        var dDate = new Date(d);
        return Math.round(dDate.getTime() / 1000);
    };
</script>
```

It outputs a timestamp value. Then from anywhere in the classic asp code, I can do this:

```
response.Write DateAdd("s", toUtcString(cDate("11/11/2012 06:25 PM")), "01/01/1970 00:00:00") 'expect 11/11/2012 10:25:00 PM gmt/utc time
response.Write DateAdd("s", toUtcString(cDate("06/11/2012 06:25 PM")), "01/01/1970 00:00:00") 'expect  6/11/2012  9:25:00 PM gmt/utc time
```

This (I believe) is simple, and it produces the expected values and fully factors in the DST.

Comment: this won't work for timestamps with values greater then subtype Long. e.g. DateAdd("s", toUtcString(cDate("01/01/2060 06:25 PM")), "01/01/1970 00:00:00")

Comment: This does not work for ISO8601 dates.
Run at server, new Date("2015-08-27T12:28:51") return NaN
Run at client Thu Aug 27 2015 11:58:16 GMT+0200
I wanted to convert UTC to local time.

Comment: @Leif Neland - That is a trivial date format issue, and not a problem with the function above.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP classic you can mix VBScript and JScript code inside one page. The JScript `Date` object could be used for local ⇄ UTC date conversion. Complete example:

```
<%@ language="vbscript" %>
<%
Option Explicit
Dim local_date
Dim utc_date
For Each local_date In Array("11/11/2012 06:25 PM", "06/11/2012 06:25 PM")
    utc_date = local_to_utc(local_date)
    Response.Write "Local: " & local_date & ", UTC: " & utc_date & vbNewLine
Next
For Each utc_date In Array("2012-11-12T02:25:00Z", "2012-06-12T01:25:00+00:00")
    local_date = utc_to_local(utc_date)
    Response.Write "UTC: " & utc_date & ", Local: " & local_date & vbNewLine
Next
%>
<script language="jscript" runat="server">
    function local_to_utc(datestr) {
        // note that this function lets JScript engine parse the date, correctly or otherwise
        var date = new Date(datestr);
        var result = date.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getUTCDate() + "T" + date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + date.getUTCSeconds();
        return result.replace(/(\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g, "$10$2") + "Z";
    }
    function utc_to_local(datestr) {
        // note that this function parses only a subset of ISO 8601 date format
        var match = datestr.match(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(?:\.(\d{3}))?(?:Z|([-+])(\d{2}):(\d{2}))$/);
        var offset = match[8] ? (match[8] === "+" ? 1 : -1) * (match[9] * 60 + match[10] * 1) : 0;
        var date = new Date(Date.UTC(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3], match[4], match[5] - offset, match[6], match[7] || 0));
        var result = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
        return result.replace(/(\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g, "$10$2");
    }
</script>
```

Expected result:

- [Nov 11 2012 18:25 PST = Nov 12 2012 02:25 UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20121112T022500&p1=234&p2=1440)
- [Jun 11 2012 18:25 PDT = Jun 12 2012 01:25 UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20120612T012500&p1=234&p2=1440)

And the output when executed on a server using PST/PDT time:

```
Local: 11/11/2012 06:25 PM,       UTC:   2012-11-12T02:25:00Z
Local: 06/11/2012 06:25 PM,       UTC:   2012-06-12T01:25:00Z
UTC:   2012-11-12T02:25:00Z,      Local: 2012-11-11 18:25:00
UTC:   2012-06-12T01:25:00+00:00, Local: 2012-06-11 18:25:00
```

Comment: Interesting. I will run some tests on this later today. Will get back to you

Comment: Works perfectly, and avoids the needs to use **Server.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")**. Moreover, it is elegant in that it allows to include jScript code directly inside the page.

Answer (score 0):

If I not miss something, you need to get local time on remote machine and it time zone offset, right?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13980554) I see self-answer based on `WMI Win32_TimeZone Bias` property. But according to this MSDN example: "[Converting Local Time to UTC Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)", quote:

> Use Win32_ComputerSystem CurrentTimeZone property, because it
>   automatically adjusts the Time Zone bias for daylight saving time
>   Win32_TimeZone Bias property does not.

So, next example function get current date time, and I'll leave to you to modify it for concrete date time measuring.

```
' "." mean local computer
WScript.Echo FormatDateTime(UTCDate("."), 0)

Function UTCDate(strComputer)
    Dim objWMIService, ColDate, ColCS

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWMIService = _
        GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
        & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set ColDate = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_LocalTime")

    UTCDate = DateSerial(100, 1, 1)
    For Each objDate In ColDate
        UTCDate = DateAdd("yyyy", ObjDate.Year - 100, UTCDate)
        UTCDate = DateAdd("m", ObjDate.Month - 1, UTCDate)
        UTCDate = DateAdd("d", ObjDate.Day - 1, UTCDate)
        UTCDate = DateAdd("h", ObjDate.Hour, UTCDate)
        UTCDate = DateAdd("n", ObjDate.Minute, UTCDate)
        UTCDate = DateAdd("s", ObjDate.Second, UTCDate)
    Next

    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696015(v=vs.85).aspx
    Set ColCS = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")

    Dim TimeZoneOffset, LocalTimeZone
    For Each LocalTimeZone In ColCS
        TimeZoneOffset = LocalTimeZone.CurrentTimeZone
    Next

    If TimeZoneOffset < 0 Then
        TimeZoneOffset = Abs(TimeZoneOffset)
    Else
        TimeZoneOffset = -Abs(TimeZoneOffset)
    End If

    UTCDate = DateAdd("n", TimeZoneOffset, UTCDate)
    If Err Then UTCDate = vbNull
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
End Function
```

[EDIT] Well, looks like should not trust on MSDN then (or maybe this work only for current time). However, I see it's not the answer you looking for. If you not find better idea, you may automate this [online calculator](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html).

**P.S.**   Ok, strike out above code and lets try another "iteration".

Just to note that I made a code compatible with my time zone (Bulgaria), where PDT start at last Sunday of March and end at last Sunday of October. This allow me to set easy my PDT range. Shortly, the idea is to make algorithm applicable to your region. The rest is clearly, I hope.

```
With New DateDrill
    Debug.WriteLine .UTCDate("2008-6-28")
    Debug.WriteLine .UTCDate("2014-1-21")
End With

Class DateDrill

    Public Function UTCDate(ByVal dtDate)
        If Not IsDate(dtDate) Then Err.Raise 5
        dtDate = CDate(dtDate)
        Dim ZoneBias: ZoneBias = TimeZoneBias()
        If IsPDT(Now) <> IsPDT(dtDate) Then
            ZoneBias = ZoneBias - 60
        End If
        UTCDate = DateAdd("n", ZoneBias, dtDate)
    End Function

    Private Function IsPDT(ByVal dtDate)
        If Not IsDate(dtDate) Then Err.Raise 5
        dtDate = CDate(dtDate)
        Dim pdtLow, pdtUpr, nDaysBack

        pdtLow = DateSerial(Year(dtDate),  3, 31)
        pdtUpr = DateSerial(Year(dtDate), 10, 31)
        pdtLow = DateAdd("h", 2, pdtLow)
        pdtUpr = DateAdd("h", 2, pdtUpr)

        nDaysBack = Weekday(pdtLow) - 1
        If nDaysBack <> 0 Then
            pdtLow = DateAdd("d", -nDaysBack, pdtLow)
        End If

        nDaysBack = Weekday(pdtUpr) - 1
        If nDaysBack <> 0 Then
            pdtUpr = DateAdd("d", -nDaysBack, pdtUpr)
        End If

        IsPDT = (dtDate >= pdtLow And dtDate <= pdtUpr)
    End Function

    Private Function TimeZoneBias()
        Dim LTZone
        With GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
                "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
            For Each LTZone In .ExecQuery(_
                    "Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")
                TimeZoneBias = LTZone.CurrentTimeZone
            Next
        End With
        TimeZoneBias = TimeZoneBias * -1
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Yes you are missing the main issue - say today, 2013-02-19, I want to covert a timestamp from say, 2008-06-05 (during daylight savings time) from PDT (my server timezone) to UTC. using the method you described will give me a value which is 60 minutes off from the correct value (because the CURRENT time is PST (not PDT), the offset will be incorrect for that historical date).

Comment: Wait a min, why you using CURRENT time? I thought you can flesh out the idea from my bone and finish the rest, or you need more help?

Comment: What I meany by "current" is that your wmi query returns the offset at time you request it, which could be different than the offset at the datetime you are trying to convert.

Comment: Ok, I see, may bad is that I trust too much on MS :)

Comment: Thanks for all of the effort.. your last iteration looks like it could do the trick. I ended up going with a different solution using javascript. Will post below.

Answer (score 0):

This little collection of ASP VBScript functions may do what you need.  I'm drawing a Unix Timestamp from a MySQL database.  Depending on you database it may be a slightly different query, but most DBs can return a Unix Timestamp.  On my server the query only takes one or two milliseconds.

Note: `pquery` is my own function for running SQL queries. Obviously substitute in your own method.

I'm calculating the offset each time `unixTime()` runs.  You could of course calculate it once in a "bootstrap" file and set a global variable if you prefer.

```
Function unixTimestamp()
    ' Unix Timestamp, drawn from MySQL because ASP doesn't natively handle time zones
    rs = pquery( "SELECT unix_timestamp() AS `ts`", null )
    unixTimestamp = cLng( rs("ts") )
End Function

Function utc_offset()
    ' Offset of Server time from UTC, in seconds
    dim unixNow : unixNow = unixTimestamp()
    dim aspNow  : aspNow  = cLng( DateDiff( "s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", now() ) )
    utc_offset = cLng( ( aspNow - unixNow ))
End Function

Function unixTime( byVal dt )
    dim offset : offset = utc_offset()
    if( VarType( dt ) = vbDate ) then
        unixTime = cLng( DateDiff( "s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", dt ) - offset )
    else
        if( isDate( dt ) ) then
            dt = cDate( dt )
            unixTime = cLng( DateDiff( "s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", dt ) - offset )
        else
            unixTime = null
        end if
    end if
End Function

Function datetimeFromUnix( byVal udt, offset )
    datetimeFromUnix = cDate( DateAdd( "s", udt + offset , "01/01/1970 00:00:00" ) )
End Function
```

Now run:

```
utcTimestamp = unixTime( dDate )
utcDate = datetimeFromUnix( utcTimestamp, 0 )   ' UTC
localDate = datetimeFromUnix( utcTimestamp, utc_offset() )  ' back where we started
```

Comment: These are nice, but unfortunately, when converting historical dates, they don't address whether or not DST was in effect at the time of the historical date (unless I am missing something or misunderstand your code)

Comment: Ouch. You are correct. And that’s a difficult one to calculate because so many different locales have different rules

Comment: Yes. Depending on specific use cases we've done things in the past where we had to have a lookup table (or whatever data structure you prefer working with) which had historical date ranges and DST start/end dates which had to be factored in to historical conversions.  Now in any new software or code I write, I usually try to save values as utc and ALSO store the source timezone/offset/dst info, just so that it's there for any future conversion work that may be needed. Overkill? Maybe. But I find this a tough problem to get around any other way.

Comment: It’s always easier to do it right in the first place! ;-)

Comment: It would be interesting to try to create an ASP class that does this for us.  Basically add "time zone" data to the Date class.  I'd say three elements: timestamp, time zone name, and the actual offset.  Add serialization/deserialization functions and you could maybe store it all in one field. For compatibility use the same Time Zone names as, say, PHP? Maybe even an encapsulated routine for calculating/converting historic offsets based on Time Zone. Hmmm.   Then of course build a time machine and do this twenty years ago!

Comment: This is a great idea actually. Would save the latency created by DB lookups for the historical conversion stuff. Next time I need to deal with this, I may just go this route.

Comment: If you do it, please post the class online! This could be really useful to anyone working with Classic ASP.  (Or did you mean the time machine? Can I borrow it? I’ll give it back ten minutes ago)

Comment: The serialized strings in the DB should still be reasonably sortable/filterable if alphabetical==chronological. You’d have to always make the timestamp UTC, (the deserialize function would reapply the offset as needed). Maybe even best in this case to make the timestamp a no-dashes Integer