# Canadian Time to display

Tags: javascript, time, asp-classic

Is there any way to show Canadian time in website ?

I am using Classic ASP and need Canadian time to display and to be store in database

Comment: Canadian time? Doesn't Canada have multiple time zones, like US and Brazil do?

Comment: This might help you if u do not want to use js.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832986/how-to-work-with-timezone-in-asp-net

Comment: Is this more or less the same question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949706/convert-time-to-utc-vbscript

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to use JS plugin, I would prefer [**timezone.js**](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) using this you can set the timezone.

Comment: This is a good solution if Dev is ready to use js.