# Classic Asp cookie expires date does not always get set

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to set cookie with addheader -method in Classic Asp which is the only way of adding among other things HttpOnly and Secure -flags to cookies. All work with the below code - but there is one exception and its is the expiration date/time.

```
<%
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "testCookie=2000; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;expires=" & dateAdd("d", 365, Now()) & ";samesite=Strict;HostOnly"
%>
```

However, it seems to be browser-related issue. In firefox I can see in the Storage tab of developer tools that expiration time is set. But in Chrome it always stays as the default which is the expiration with the end of session. This same issue is with the Edge too.

Has anyone any experience with this issue?

Comment: Can you include the actual output of this? What format does `dateAdd("d", 365, Now())` return? This may be your issue.

Comment: It returns the following format: 2/13/2021 10:08:31 PM. Is this is of any help?

Comment: Is there some spesific format for the expiration date/time for Chrome to understand it? - I have tried to variate the format without any success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expected date format is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date#Syntax). You need to produce expiration date in that manner.

In Classic ASP, you can use server-side JavaScript to produce such dates easily.

```vb
<!--#include file="HTTPDate.asp"-->
<%
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "testCookie=2000; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;expires=" & HTTPDate(DateAdd("d", 365, Now())) & ";samesite=Strict;HostOnly"
%>
```

HTTPDate.asp

```js
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
function HTTPDate(vbsDate){
    return (new Date(vbsDate)).toGMTString().replace(/UTC/, "GMT");
}
</script>
```

Edit: Pure VBScript solution added.

```
<%
Function CurrentTZO()
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
        CurrentTZO = .RegRead( _ 
        "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias")
    End With
End Function

Function Pad(text)
    Pad = Right("00" & text, 2)
End Function

Function HTTPDate(ByVal localDate)
    localDate = DateAdd("n", CurrentTZO(), localDate)

    ' WeekdayName and MonthName functions relies on locale
    ' need to produce day and month name abbreviations in en-US locale
    Dim locale : locale = SetLocale("en-US")

    Dim out(5)
    out(0) = WeekdayName(Weekday(localDate), True) & ","
    out(1) = Pad(Day(localDate))
    out(2) = MonthName(Month(localDate), True)
    out(3) = Year(localDate)
    out(4) = Join(Array(Pad(Hour(localDate)), Pad(Minute(localDate)), Pad(Second(localDate))), ":")
    out(5) = "GMT"

    SetLocale locale ' set original locale back 

    HTTPDate = Join(out, " ")
End Function

Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "testCookie=2000; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;expires=" & HTTPDate(DateAdd("d", 365, Now())) & ";samesite=Strict;HostOnly"
%>
```

Comment: Kul-Tigin, yes, you solved it, now cookies expiration is also set in Crome and Edge,  well done!

Comment: @M.Y. I added a pure VBScript solution.

Comment: Yes, indeed you did - nice implementation. However by using "max-age" instead of "expires" brings the original issue back - i.e. the cookie expires with default value of end of session.

Comment: @M.Y. Thanks. It was my fault, they must have been `expires`. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted solution of Kul-Tigin I want to add also a vbscript solution for those who are missing that too.

```
<%
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "testCookie=2000; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;expires=" & (New UTC).toUTCString(500,"d") & ";samesite=Strict;HostOnly;"


Class UTC

    Public Function toUTCString(ByVal offSet, ByVal offsetType)
        ' ***********************************
        ' Converts vbScript datetime format to 
        ' Universal datetime string format:
        ' Tue, 16 Feb 2021 13:39:24 GMT
        '************************************

        Dim dt: dt = dateAdd(offsetType, offSet, UTCDate(Now()))
        Dim tdParts: tdParts = Split(dt, " ")
        Dim tPart: tPart = CDate(tdParts(1) & " " & tdParts(2))
        Dim dPart: dPart = CDate(tdParts(0))

        Dim timeTo24: timeTo24 = _
        Right("0" & Hour(tPart), 2) & ":" & _
        Right("0" & Minute(tPart), 2) & ":" & _
        Right("0" & Second(tPart), 2)

        toUTCString = WeekdayName(Weekday(dPart), True) & ", " & _
                      Day(dPart) & " " & _
                      MonthName(Month(dPart), True) & " " & _
                      Year(dPart) & " " & _
                      timeTo24 & " GMT"

    End Function


    Public Function UTCDate(ByVal dtDate)
        If Not IsDate(dtDate) Then Err.Raise 5
        dtDate = CDate(dtDate)
        Dim ZoneBias: ZoneBias = TimeZoneBias()
        If IsPDT(Now) <> IsPDT(dtDate) Then
            ZoneBias = ZoneBias - 60
        End If
        UTCDate = DateAdd("n", ZoneBias, dtDate)
    End Function

    Private Function IsPDT(ByVal dtDate)
        If Not IsDate(dtDate) Then Err.Raise 5
        dtDate = CDate(dtDate)
        Dim pdtLow, pdtUpr, nDaysBack

        pdtLow = DateSerial(Year(dtDate),  3, 31)
        pdtUpr = DateSerial(Year(dtDate), 10, 31)
        pdtLow = DateAdd("h", 2, pdtLow)
        pdtUpr = DateAdd("h", 2, pdtUpr)

        nDaysBack = Weekday(pdtLow) - 1
        If nDaysBack <> 0 Then
            pdtLow = DateAdd("d", -nDaysBack, pdtLow)
        End If

        nDaysBack = Weekday(pdtUpr) - 1
        If nDaysBack <> 0 Then
            pdtUpr = DateAdd("d", -nDaysBack, pdtUpr)
        End If

        IsPDT = (dtDate >= pdtLow And dtDate <= pdtUpr)
    End Function

    Private Function TimeZoneBias()
        Dim LTZone
        With GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
                "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
            For Each LTZone In .ExecQuery(_
                    "Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem")
                TimeZoneBias = LTZone.CurrentTimeZone
            Next
        End With
        TimeZoneBias = TimeZoneBias * -1
    End Function

End Class

%>
```

Comment: This approach missing a critical point: Time Zone. In addition to the format, produced date has to be in GMT. You need to convert the local time (`Now()` in this example) to GMT first, only then it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for pinpointing the error - I try to fix it, when the time permits, according to your advice.

Comment: Now I have tried to fix it (see edits in my code) by using and adopting the class given here in the end part of discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949706/convert-time-to-utc-vbscript/14970037.  Is this now what solves the issue you picked up?

Comment: Did not work with my computer's locale configuration. `en-GB` for example. Put a `SetLocale "en-GB"` line on top of your script to reproduce the issue. Other than that, it seems to be working.

Comment: I get also error (from server log: |27|800a0009|Subscript_out_of_range:_'[number:_2]' HTTP/1.1)  whenever I use SetLocale in the beginning of the script with any locale value. Error takes place at line Dim dt: dt = dateAdd(offsetType, offSet, UTCDate(Now()))). Note that I run the code at production envirnment, not at localhost of my PC.

Comment: Now I noticed that locale "en-us" (1033)  only works - and that is probably due to my production server locating there.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to write a cookie with classic asp

```vb
Response.Cookies("cookies_name") = "cookies_value"
Response.Cookies("cookies_name").Expires = date+360 ' +360 days
Response.Cookies("cookies_name").Secure = true
```

For additional parameters see [learn.microsoft.com (IIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524757(v=vs.90)) and [learn.microsoft.com (aspnet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178194(v=vs.100))