# How can I create an event in a time zone other than the calendar's time zone?

Tags: .net, google-api

I'm using the Google API from .NET (VB.NET, to be precise), and it's creating events in a way I don't understand.

My calendar is in Eastern time, and I'm trying to create an event that will be at a fixed time in *another* time zone.  Specifically, I want to make an event that will happen at 1:00 PM in *local time in Los Angeles*.

This is my code:

```
Dim dStart As New DateTime(2014, 1, 30, 13, 0, 0)
Dim dEnd = dStart.AddHours(2)

e.Start = New EventDateTime With {.DateTime = dStart, .TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"}
e.End = New EventDateTime With {.DateTime = dEnd, .TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"}

Dim ins As New InsertRequest(service, e, calendar.Id)
ins.Execute()
```

I expected this to make an event like this:

```
1/30/2014 @ 1:00PM (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time
```

But instead, it created this event:

```
1/30/2014 @ 10:00AM (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time
```

In other words, it knows to use Pacific time, but it does this *and* subtracts three hours.  Why does it do this, and how can I create an event with the right time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EventDateTime.DateTime* always counts with **your local time zone** So you have to set Date in your time zone. In this case is *EventDateTime.TimeZone* is used only to display time offset - in your case (GMT-8) but will not affect time itself

```
Dim dStart As New DateTime(2014, 1, 30, 13 - myTimeZone + targetTimeZone, 0, 0)
```

Check this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980541/how-can-i-determine-my-time-zone-offset-using-vbscript), How to determine time zone difference

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do.  So you're saying that the time zone is not actually used for anything other than saying "Pacific Time"?  That seems really counter-intuitive.

Comment: I spent some time on [similar](http://daily-reservation.appspot.com/) issue, than decided to go through UTC (hour - myTimeZone + targetTimeZone)

Comment: That's what I'll do, thanks.  But it still seems a bit klunky to me.

Comment: Do not forget, that you are passing DateTime Object which already contain your local timeZone :) To prove just change your local time zone to another and you will see. If you omit EventDateTime.TimeZone it will use google calendar default time zone for particular calendar in display